# Cannot enable state and country picklist

Tags: data

I've gone through all the steps in order to convert the address fields into state and country picklists however when clicking 'Finish and Enable Picklists' nothing happens at all and I don't get a response. There is no other deployments happening so it shouldn't interfere. The only other solution that I have seen is people manually mapping the data in excel and dataloader then enabling it but isn't there any other way?

This is the following documentation that I have followed: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.admin_state_country_picklist_enable.htm&type=5

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a link to the documentation you followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running into the same issue, I contacted Salesforce support and following the steps in this article resolved my issue:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000314667